# How can you animate changing color of nodes in JUNG

Tags: java, graphics, jung

I have a graph visualized through JUNG library .

Now i want to change the color of my particular vertex(which meets a particular condition) for a while ,lets say 1 second , and then change it back to the original color . 
I want to do it for all my vertices one by one . How could i achieve this .

The current code i have just make all the vertices change color all at once and not one by one. How can i change the color back to it's orginal color and take one vertex at a time .

```
Transformer<Integer, Paint> vertexPaint = new Transformer<Integer, Paint>() {
        private final Color palette =  Color.GREEN;

        public Paint transform(Integer i) {

                     for(int j =0;j<l2.size();j++){
                         if(i == Integer.valueOf(j)){
                             return Color.BLUE;


                         }

                     }  

                     return palette;
        }
    };
```

Comment: You could use a Timer? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html